# Shell command line program

Tags: c, recursion, pointers, posix

I have refactored a `for` loop into a function. I'm still a beginner at using C utility functions such as `strtok`, `strdup`, `malloc` and`strcpy`. The program makes the correct output for another program (my program is a [shell command language interpretor](https://github.com/montao/openshell)) showing that I have 1800 lines of code:

```
 $ cat *.c *.h|wc -l
 {cat} {errors.c} {main.c} {util.c} {CommandEntry.h} {do.h} {errors.h} {openshell.h} {|} {wc} {-l} {|}
p[0][0] cat
p[0][1] errors.c
p[0][2] main.c
p[0][3] util.c
p[0][4] CommandEntry.h
p[0][5] do.h
p[0][6] errors.h
p[0][7] openshell.h
p[1][0] wc
p[1][1] -l

1833
```

You can see the strategy I used was to use a matrix `A[i][j]` for a command language program where element `[i][j]` is program `i`, argument `j`.

The functions I have refactored are:

```
void write_command(int *w, char *argv[], char *string[]) {
    for (int r = 0; argv[r] != NULL; r++) {
        string[r] = strdup(argv[r]);
    }
}

void write_argument(int *argc, char *argv[], char *string[]) {
    int j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < *argc; j++) {
        string[j] = strdup(argv[j]);
    }
}
```

The large function that calls those functions is:

```
static int runCmd(const char *cmd) {
    const char *cp;
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    struct command structcommand[15];
    char **argv = 0;
    int argc = 1;
    bool pipe = false;
    char *string[z][z];
    char *pString3[40];
    char *pString2[40];
    int n = 0;
    char **ptr1;
    char string1[z];
    bool keep = false;
    char *pString1[z];
    char *pString[z];
    *pString1 = "\0";
    *pString = "\0";
    char *temp = {'\0'};
    int w = 0;
    bool b = false;
    int j = 0;
    int i;
    int p = 0;
    char **ptr;
    char *tmpchar;
    char *cmdtmp;
    bool b1 = false;
    int y = 0;
    i = 0;
    int h = 0;
    nullterminate(string);
    if (cmd) {
        for (cp = cmd; *cp; cp++) {
            if ((*cp >= 'a') && (*cp <= 'z')) {
                continue;
            }
            if ((*cp >= 'A') && (*cp <= 'Z')) {
                continue;
            }
            if (isDecimal(*cp)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (isBlank(*cp)) {
                continue;
            }
            if ((*cp == '.') || (*cp == '/') || (*cp == '-') ||
                (*cp == '+') || (*cp == '=') || (*cp == '_') ||
                (*cp == ':') || (*cp == ',') || (*cp == '\'') ||
                (*cp == '"')) {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    if (cmd) {
        cmdtmp = malloc(sizeof(char *) * strlen(cmd) + 1);
        strcpy(cmdtmp, cmd);
        tmpchar = malloc(sizeof(char *) * strlen(cmd) + 1);
        if (tmpchar == NULL) {
            printf("Error allocating memory!\n"); /* print an error message */
            return 1; /* return with failure */
        }
        strcpy(tmpchar, cmd);
        ptr1 = str_split(pString3, cmdtmp, '|');
        if (strstr(cmd, "|") == NULL) {         /* not a pipeline */

            makeArgs(cmd, &argc, (const char ***) &argv, pipe, 0, 0);
            write_argument(&argc, argv, string[0]);
            n++;
        }
        else {
            for (i = 0; *(ptr1 + i); i++) { /* tokenize the input string for each pipeline*/
                n++; /* save number of pipelines */
                int e = 0; /* a counter */
                *pString = "\0"; /* should malloc and free this? */
                strcpy(string1, *(ptr1 + i));
                if ((string1[0] != '\0') && !isspace(string1[0])) { /* this is neither the end nor a new argument */
                    ptr = str_split(pString2, *(&string1), ' '); /* split the string at the arguments */
                    h = 0;
                    for (j = 0; *(ptr + j); j++) { /* step through the arguments */
                        /* the pipeline is in cmdtmp and the argument/program is in ptr[i] */
                        if (ptr + j && !b && strstr(*(ptr + j), "'")) {
                            b = true;
                            strcpy(temp, *(ptr + j));
                            if (y < 1) {
                                y++;
                            }
                        }
                        while (b) {
                            if (*(ptr + j) && strstr(*(ptr + j), "'")) { /* end of quote */
                                b = false;
                                if (y < 1) {
                                    string[i][j] = strcpy(temp, *(ptr + j));
                                }
                                y = 0;
                            }
                            else if (*(ptr + j)) { /* read until end of quote */
                                string[i][j] = temp;
                                continue;
                            } else {
                                b = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (ptr + j) {
                            if (*(ptr + j)[0] == '{') {
                                keep = true;
                            }
                            if (testFn(*(ptr + j))) { /* test for last char */
                                string[i][j - p] = concat(*pString1, *(ptr + j));
                                keep = false;
                                free(*pString1);
                                goto mylabel;
                            }
                            if (keep) {
                                *pString1 = concat(*pString1, *(ptr + j));
                                *pString1 = concat(*pString1, " ");
                                p++;
                            } else {
                                b1 = false;
                                int q = j;
                                for (e = 0; *(ptr + q + e); e++) { /* step through the string */
                                    b1 = true;
                                    if (*(ptr + e + q)) {
                                        *pString = concat(*pString, *(ptr + e + q));
                                        *pString = concat(*pString, " ");
                                    }
                                    j = e;
                                }
                                if (makeArgs(*pString, &argc, (const char ***) &argv, pipe, i, h)) {
                                    write_command(&w, argv, string[w]);
                                    w++;

                                } else {
                                    if (!b1) { /* no args (?) */
                                        for (int r = 0; argv[r] != NULL; r++) {
                                            string[i][r] = argv[r];
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    mylabel:
                    free(ptr);
                    dump_argv((const char *) "d", argc, argv);
                }
            }
            free(ptr1);
            free(cmdtmp);
            free(tmpchar);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; DEBUG && string[i][j] != NULL; j++) {
                if (i == 0 && j == 0) printf("\n");
                printf("p[%d][%d] %s\n", i, j, string[i][j]);
            }
            structcommand[i].argv = string[i];
        }
        fflush(NULL);
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("fork failed");
            return -1;
        }
        /* If we are the child process, then go execute the string.*/
        if (pid == 0) {
            /* spawn(cmd);*/
            fork_pipes(n, structcommand);
        }
        /*
         * We are the parent process.
         * Wait for the child to complete.
         */
        status = 0;
        while (((pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) < 0) && (errno == EINTR));
        if (pid < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error from waitpid: %s", strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }
        if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "pid %ld: killed by signal %d\n",
                    (long) pid, WTERMSIG(status));

            return -1;
        }
    }
    return WEXITSTATUS(status);


}
```

My strategy is to factor out all the loops and make every loop a function and then the code will be more readable (hopefully). I'm also interested if you have a refactoring strategy for my case.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You really need to reduce the scope of all your variables, and give them proper names. As it is, your code is impossible to follow, it's super hard to guess the type of anything, treacherous to determine whether it's been initialized properly or not, or whether it needs to be cleaned up. Discovering unused or redundant variables is pretty much impossible too.

And this penalizes you for refactoring: since all your variable declarations are bunched up at the top with opaque names, potential function boundaries are super hard to figure out. You don't know which parts of your code need what variables, what side-effects need to be visible to what blocks, etc.

Even your two refactored functions raise questions.

```
void write_command(int *w, char *argv[], char *string[]) {
    for (int r = 0; argv[r] != NULL; r++) {
        string[r] = strdup(argv[r]);
    }
}
```

What is `w`? It's not used, why have it as an argument? `write_*` is not a good prefix for something that duplicates something else. `dup_*` or `copy_*` would be more understandable. `argv` is sort of understood in C to be an args list, so that's ok. But `string` for a variable name is terrible. Try this:

```
void copy_args(char *source[], char *target[]) { /* ... */ }
```

The body is ok, but why `r` as a loop variable? `i` is the "default" unless you want to give it a meaningful name. `r` isn't meaningful, so it is suspicious.

```
void write_argument(int *argc, char *argv[], char *string[]) {
    int j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < *argc; j++) {
        string[j] = strdup(argv[j]);
    }
}
```

Again, wrong prefix name for something that copies/duplicates. Same remark for the argument names. Now why is `argc` passed by pointer? It is only read in the function. And why declare `j` outside the loop? That extends its scope for no good reason. Plus you end up initializing it to zero twice - the compiler will optimize that out but why do it at all?

```
void copy_first_args(int n, char *source[], char *target[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        target[i] = strdup(source[i]);
    }
}
```

---

The following needs to die.

```
const char *cp;
pid_t pid;
int status;
struct command structcommand[15];
char **argv = 0;
int argc = 1;
bool pipe = false;
char *string[z][z];
char *pString3[40];
char *pString2[40];
int n = 0;
char **ptr1;
char string1[z];
bool keep = false;
char *pString1[z];
char *pString[z];
*pString1 = "\0";
*pString = "\0";
char *temp = {'\0'};
int w = 0;
bool b = false;
int j = 0;
int i;
int p = 0;
char **ptr;
char *tmpchar;
char *cmdtmp;
bool b1 = false;
int y = 0;
i = 0;
int h = 0;
nullterminate(string);
```

There is no consistency at all, it is a jumbled mess of inscrutable names, random initializations, perplexing assignments and a scary function call - `nullterminate` takes a 2D array of pointers, with no size indication and you give it an uninitialized array? Sounds like a bug waiting to happen.

Looking at the toplevel flow of your function, you don't need a single one of those declared at the top. Except `status`. But there's a bug there. If `!cmd`, your function will return something based on `status` that has not been initialized => undefined behavior. That's exactly the sort of problem this "style" of declaring everything at the top and not initializing them consistently brings.

Also `z` appears to be a global name (variable? constant? macro? who knowns). That's a terrible name for a global. Find a better, longer one. This is especially important for globals.

---

Structure of that function:

```
int runCmd(const char *cmd) {
  /* decls */
  if (cmd) { /* 1. chunk of code that doesn't do anything */ }
  if (cmd) { /* 2. unreasonably large chunk of code */ }
  return stuff;
}
```

Problems:

- As noted before, if `!cmd` you return junk
- Two different `if` blocks in a row with the same condition is suspicious, only makes sense if the first chunk could affect the conditional. But it doesn't.
- One of the blocks doesn't actually do anything.

You'll win one level of nesting and a tiny bit less confusion for the readers by laying it out like this instead:

```
int runCmd(const char *cmd) {
  if (!cmd) { return error; /* or assert */ }
  /* code */
}
```

---

I'll just look at the next few lines of code:

```
cmdtmp = malloc(sizeof(char *) * strlen(cmd) + 1);
strcpy(cmdtmp, cmd);
```

You know about `strdup`, use it. The allocation above will be about eight times too large on usual 64bit platforms - what you should have there is `sizeof(char)`, not `char*`, or just `strlen(cmd)+1` since by definition `sizeof(char) == 1`.

```
tmpchar = malloc(sizeof(char *) * strlen(cmd) + 1);
if (tmpchar == NULL) {
    printf("Error allocating memory!\n"); /* print an error message */
    return 1; /* return with failure */
}
strcpy(tmpchar, cmd);
```

Same remark. Except why did you check this allocation but not the previous one? Be consistent. Either ignore all allocation failures or deal with all of them consistently.

```
ptr1 = str_split(pString3, cmdtmp, '|');
if (strstr(cmd, "|") == NULL) {         /* not a pipeline */

    makeArgs(cmd, &argc, (const char ***) &argv, pipe, 0, 0);
    write_argument(&argc, argv, string[0]);
    n++;
} else { // ...
```

So your code duplicates `cmd` twice, splits one copy based on a delimiter, then checks if the delimiter was present in the first place and does stuff that doesn't need either copy or the result of the split if it wasn't. `pipe` appears out of nowhere, let's hope it's been initialized. This is all very suspicious.

So a quick grep:

```
$ grep tmpchar t.c
    char *tmpchar;
        tmpchar = malloc(sizeof(char *) * strlen(cmd) + 1);
        if (tmpchar == NULL) {
        strcpy(tmpchar, cmd);
            free(tmpchar);
$ grep cmdtmp t.c
    char *cmdtmp;
        cmdtmp = malloc(sizeof(char *) * strlen(cmd) + 1);
        strcpy(cmdtmp, cmd);
        ptr1 = str_split(pString3, cmdtmp, '|');
                        /* the pipeline is in cmdtmp and the argument/program is in ptr[i] */
            free(cmdtmp);
$ grep pipe t.c
    bool pipe = false;
        if (strstr(cmd, "|") == NULL) {         /* not a pipeline */
            makeArgs(cmd, &argc, (const char ***) &argv, pipe, 0, 0);
            for (i = 0; *(ptr1 + i); i++) { /* tokenize the input string for each pipeline*/
                n++; /* save number of pipelines */
                        /* the pipeline is in cmdtmp and the argument/program is in ptr[i] */
                                if (makeArgs(*pString, &argc, (const char ***) &argv, pipe, i, h)) {
            fork_pipes(n, structcommand);
```

And here's what transpires:

- `tmpchar` is in fact not used.
- `cmdtmp` is only used as the source of the split.
- Both are leaked if there was no separator (notice the extra indent before the `free`).
- `pipe` is a boolean that is always false.

Here are your first steps in being able to refactor this:

- get rid of `tmpchar`
- get rid of `cmdtmp`
- get rid of `pipe`
- rename `makeArgs` to `make_args` or change the other ones to use `funkyCase` - pick one style and stick to it.
- modify `str_split` to do the copying of its input string if it needs to (e.g. if it uses `strtok` on it), and return a struct that has the number of "chunks" it split out and the list of chunks.
- create a struct for the individual commands and arguments. It should have something like the "executable" name, number of args and arg list. Create a few functions to create such a struct, free it, and add to the argument list.

Then your function can start to look like this:

```
int run_cmd(const char *cmd) {
  assert(cmd);
  struct str_list *chunks = str_split(cmd, '|');
  struct pipeline *pipe = alloc_pipeline(chunks->size);
  for (int i=0; i<chunks->size; i++) {
    pipe->command[i] = parse_command(chunks->data[i]);
  }
  int status = execute_pipeline(pipe);
  free_pipeline(pipe);
  free_str_list(chunks);
  return status;
}
```

---

There's probably a lot to be said about your parsing code, but with those variable names and way too big scopes, I just skipped right over it. Write helper functions for common tasks. Use `ptr[i]` instead of `*(ptr+i)`. `goto` might be ok, but the label name you chose is meaningless.

---

Last quibble:

```
 printf("Error allocating memory!\n"); /* print an error message */
 int e = 0; /* a counter */
```

Those comments are not useful. First one is just redundant, second one is yet another indication that your variable names are not good. If it's a counter, give it a name that tells people that it is a counter and what sort of thing it counts!

Comment: 2 days later the code looks very different but I'm still refactoring the same function. The loops have gotten much better, I've taken care of all memory leaks using valgrind but the number of variables have gotten worse. I'm not sure what I can do about the part that needs to die but I'm sure at least I can improve the naming. I'm still a beginner at this detailed level of C and RAM but I like it even when it is difficult. My strategies is to break out the loops and check with a truth table which conditions are the same and how they differ, then the function might become readable.

Comment: Look at each variable and where they are used. Then move the declaration to the latest possible time/smallest block it can be declared in and move it there. e.g. `cp` is only used in the block of code that does nothing - remove it. `pid` is used starting at the fork, so remove it from the header and `pid_t pid = fork()` instead. Then look at where `structcommand` is used, give it a proper name and move the declaration to the right spot, just before where you write to it. Repeat for all the others.

Comment: It feels difficult to reduce the scope because I need everything in memory. I've managed to break out loops and I will check the conditions if some are the same. I'm also checking with Valgrind that there is no memory leak and there isn't. I scripted a test so that I can quickly test that I don't break old functions. I think it's a nice way to learn C. I hope I can reduce the scope of my variables. I'm reading your answer again to see that I'm addressing every advice from you. Now I'm going to try and find how I can reduce the scope and put variables in smaller functions.

Comment: The link to my repository https://github.com/montao/openshell

Comment: Do you think it is ok if I use arrays instead of struct? Commands and arguments are already represented as arrays. The function `str_split` takes three arguments, but I haven't refactored it yet: `  struct str_list *chunks = str_split(pString7, cmd, '|');` This statement does not compile. But I did succeed in lowering the nesting and decreasing the scope of variables. I will try and ask a new question when I have addressed everything you answered about.